# Return observables timing issues

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a very common issue in my app and I can't find a proper solution. I have methods that MAY need to open a confirmation modal where the user can choose yes or no.

```
  checkData1 = (): Observable<any> => {
    this.subject = new Subject<boolean>();

    if (somethingIsTrue) {
      this.openConfirmationModal('Blah blah. Do you want to proceed?').subscribe(res => {
      this.subject.next(true);  // yes pressed
      }, err => {
        this.subject.next(false);  // no pressed
      });
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => { this.subject.next(true); }, 200);  // no modal, proceed
    }

    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

Here if somethingIsTrue we open a confirmation modal, or else we immediately return the true subject. I have to wrap it in a setTimeout because if I don't then it returns before the observable is subscribed to.

The problem with this is I have about 10 methods than run in a row with this setup, so

1. The 200 milliseconds add up to a bit of a delay that I am not happy with.
2. I don't have full certainty that 200 milliseconds is enough time, and I dont want to increase it.

Does anyone have suggestions so I can do this better without the setTimeout?

Answer (score 2):

You most probably wouldn't need the subscription inside this `checkData1()` function. You could use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function to conditionally return an observable.

You could then use [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) function to return boolean as observable and operators [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) and [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) to transform the emission from the modal observable.

```js
import { Observable, iif, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

checkData1 = () : Observable<boolean> => iif(
  () => somethingIsTrue,
  this.openConfirmationModal('Do you want to proceed?').pipe(
    map(() => true),
    catchError(() => of(false)) // <-- `catchError` must return an observable, hence the `of()`
  ),
  of(true)
);
```

Comment: Great answer man, you could also change the return type to `Observable<boolean>` instead of `Observable<any>`

Comment: @StPaulis: That's true, I've adjusted it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had never even heard of iif. For some reason when somethingIsTrue is false, it hits the of(true) but then it hits the truthy part of iif. I did dumb my code down for the question, instead of opening the modal I am making a database call with subscribe and getting errors with typing. I am sure I'll figure it out, thanks again.

Comment: Ok I just realized both truthy and falsy functions will be called so iif can return the correct one. I will need to use another approach but thanks for showing me this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not tested, but I thing that you want something like this:

```
checkData1 = (): Observable<boolean> => {
  let response: Observable<boolean>;

  if (somethingIsTrue) {
      response = this.openConfirmationModal('Blah blah. Do you want to proceed?')
        .pipe(
          map(() => true),
          catchError(() => of(false))  
        );
  } else {
    response = of(true);
  }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: I would change `this.response = new Observable<boolean>();` to `this.response: Observable<boolean>;` as the new Observable you are creating there is never being used.

Comment: Thank you @peinearydevelopment!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ReplaySubject` to replay the most recently emitted items for new subscribers. For example, the replay subject `new ReplaySubject(1)` will replay the last item to new subscribers.

Alternatively, you could use a `BehaviorSubject`, which has similar behavior, but you must instantiate it with a default item, and it does not replay `error` or `complete` events.

Comment: In my use case a simple Subject is more appropriate (I dont need an initial value) and I still have the same problem, I cant return the observable immediately or it wont be subscribed to in time.